# Link requires double-click to function: why?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, hyperlink, double-click

Please go here and click on the link twice: http://bogsorken.com/test/index.html

It will open up a fancybox window with a Vimeo video embedment inside. Now, I have spent all day trying to figure out **why** the link requires a double click. Is there someone more experienced than me that can solve this puzzle? Note that when you have clicked on it once, then it will only require one click, until you refresh the page.

Obviously, I want the link to function with only one click.

Comment: I haven't spent a lot of time investigating, but FF and IE throw an error: $(".nivoSlider").nivoSlider is not a function   It may have noting to do with it, but I suggest fixing that and trying again.

Comment: Not sure if this is causing it, but there's a Javascript error happening on page load, coming from this line: $('.nivoSlider').nivoSlider({
  directionNavHide:true,
  controlNav:false
 }); Also, when I try and execute the fancyBox function on the element ($("#vimeo_autoplay").fancybox(video_fancybox)) AFTER page load, it works fine

Comment: Okay, I removed the nivoSlider from the script, but the same issue is still current. Any ideas? I must admit that in all my years of playing around with code, this one must be the most bizarre one... I don't know if I am allowed to request this, but if you are as baffled as I am, kindly upvote this and maybe some programmer with magic skills will solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**: changed after conversation with op in comments.

Well it appears we were using it entirely improperly. Just instantiate the fancybox at doc.ready and wait for the click as usual. No click handlers, that's fancyboxes job.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6Z6C/13/)

```
$("#vimeo_autoplay").fancybox({
    'href' : 'http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=18669276&amp;autoplay=1',
    'opacity'       : true,
    'overlayColor'  : '#000',
    'overlayOpacity' : 0.8,
    'centerOnScroll' : false,
    'titlePosition' : 'over',
    'width' : 720,
    'height' : 405,
    'type' : 'swf',
    'swf' : {
    'wmode' : 'transparent',
    'allowfullscreen' : 'true'
    }

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing something with `video_fancybox`?

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I uploaded it to the server so you can review your solutions if you wish: http://bogsorken.com/test2/index.html

Comment: @Eric you're right, I forgot to use the settings object in the facybox  call. fixt

Comment: @Sinetheta Still doesn't work. I added your edited version, it is live now but the double-click still exists.

Comment: @AlehandroDarie You sure about that? I'm still seeing the old file, with the extend call in it.

Comment: @Sinetheta Did you refresh? Please check again: http://bogsorken.com/test2/index.html I copy and pasted your code as it currently is. You can feel free to compare. Any other ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: You are a star, thank you very much buddy. It works like a charm!